# Add bindings to button using a decorator or another option?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on adding functionality into our WPF application, the gist of which is if the user Ctl+Shift clicks on a tab, the tab is moved into a new window (the goal of which is dual monitor support).

I have been trying to find a way to make this logic easy to implement on a new element, my first thought was by use of a decorator but I can find no example nor think of a way to achieve this.

Here is a snippet of the xaml that handles this logic:

```
 <TabItem Header="Overview" TabIndex="6" x:Name="overviewTabItem" Style="{StaticResource UDTab_SecondaryTabItem}">
                    <TabItem.InputBindings>
                      <MouseBinding Gesture="CTRL+Shift+LeftClick" Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"/>
                    </TabItem.InputBindings>
                    <OverviewControl:OverviewControl x:Name="overviewControl"/>
                </TabItem>
```

The part that I would like to apply via a decorator (or other method) is the InputBindings, by necessity it would need to be able to merge in with any additional manually specified bindings a control may have.

The command for this binding, in its final state, will exist on a static object so data context shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution ended up being painfully simple and I'm ashamed I didn't think of it sooner.
I created a new class called PopoutTabItem which inherited from TabItem and then I set up the bindings I needed in the constructor.

Here is the code:

```
    public class PopoutTabItem : TabItem
{
    public PopoutTabItem()
    {
        InputBindings.Add(new MouseBinding
            {
                Gesture = new MouseGesture{Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift, MouseAction = MouseAction.LeftClick},
                Command = PopoutManager.ShowPopupCommand,
                CommandParameter = this
            });
    }
}
```

And the Xaml:

```
<TabControls:PopoutTabItem Header="Overview" TabIndex="6" x:Name="overviewTabItem" Style="{StaticResource UDTab_SecondaryTabItem}">
                    <OverviewControl:OverviewControl x:Name="overviewControl"/>
                </TabControls:PopoutTabItem>
```

Comment: you did not mention that solution should be only for TabItem objects :) it looks like any control with InputBinding should be ready to participate

Comment: Not specifically only for TabItems, the goal is for the primary code to be generic as possible. But with this solution I could encapsulate the bindings set within my static manager and just implement a new sub class that pulls down those bindings for any new elements I need to support. And I much prefer c# to xaml lol.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see how decorator can help here.

You can create custom `MyMouseBinding: MouseBinding` and then reuse it with other controls.

```
<TabItem Header="Overview" TabIndex="6" x:Name="overviewTabItem">
 <TabItem.InputBindings>
      <local:MyMouseBinding />
      <!-- Other inputs -->
 </TabItem.InputBindings>          
</TabItem>
```

The second solution is to use Attached Behaviour, it can look like

```
<TabItem Header="Overview" TabIndex="6" x:Name="overviewTabItem"
  local:MoveToSecondMonitorGesture>
     <TabItem.InputBindings>
          <!-- Other inputs -->
     </TabItem.InputBindings>          
</TabItem>
```

Comment: That wasn't my question at all, and I will clarify now that as is the binding I listed works as expected if I press ctrl, shift and click on the overview tab the command is run.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification that would indeed work, though I did manage to find a simpler way to achieve my goal.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there will be only TabItem objects then YES, your solution is more clear.